# Ubuntu desktop 22.04 LTS network settings missing yet network is working

Tags: networking

Running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on an HP Proliant ML310e Gen8 V2 with integrated Broadcom ethernet ports. Network is fully functional with internet access. Network Settings and Advanced Network Settings in the GUI are empty. The command "lshw -C network" returns the following data:

```
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 00
       serial: ec:b1:d7:f3:0c:94
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=5.15.0-48-generic duplex=full firmware=5720-v1.39 NCSI v1.3.16.0 ip=10.1.0.163 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:fabf0000-fabfffff memory:fabe0000-fabeffff memory:fabd0000-fabdffff memory:bc000000-bc01ffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
       logical name: eno2
       version: 00
       serial: ec:b1:d7:f3:0c:95
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=5.15.0-48-generic firmware=5720-v1.39 NCSI v1.3.16.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 memory:fabc0000-fabcffff memory:fabb0000-fabbffff memory:faba0000-fabaffff memory:bc020000-bc03ffff*>
```

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Please EDIT the question as that LONG block of continuous writing is next to impossible to read.

Comment: There aren't Network Settings or GUI in a server edition. It is configured with [netplan](https://netplan.io/examples/), so..., nothing to fix there.